# Fortran function returning allocatable array

Tags: function, fortran, allocatable-array

Let me consider a function returning an `allocatable` array. Should the array variable holding the result (outside the function) be allocated before an assignment?

Consider, e.g., the following program

```
program mem
  implicit none

  interface
     function get_matrix() result(res)
       real(kind=kind(0.d0)), allocatable :: res(:,:)
     end function get_matrix
  end interface
  
  real(kind=kind(0.d0)), allocatable :: w(:,:)

  allocate(w(2,2)) ! Is this necessary?
  w=get_matrix()
  deallocate(w)

end program mem

function get_matrix() result(res)
  real(kind=kind(0.d0)), allocatable :: res(:,:)

  allocate(res(2,2))
  res = 0.d0
  res(1, 1) = 1.d0
  res(2, 2) = 1.d0
end function get_matrix
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21551637/8769985), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55068396), the array `res` allocated for the result of `get_matrix` is deallocated as soon as it goes out of scope.

Would an assignment to a non-allocated variable `w` in the main program prolong the scope of the result of `get_matrix`? In other words, if I omit `allocate(w(2,2))` in the main program, do I get an undefined behavior?

Omitting `allocate(w(2,2))` and compiling with `gfortran 9.2.0` and options `-Wall -std=f2008` gives following warnings

```
mem.f90:13:0:

   13 |   w=get_matrix()
      | 
Warning: ‘w.offset’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
mem.f90:13:0: Warning: ‘w.dim[0].lbound’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
mem.f90:13:0: Warning: ‘w.dim[0].ubound’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
mem.f90:13:0: Warning: ‘w.dim[1].lbound’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
mem.f90:13:0: Warning: ‘w.dim[1].ubound’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
mem.f90:13:0:

   13 |   w=get_matrix()
      | 
Warning: ‘w.dim[0].lbound’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
mem.f90:13:0: Warning: ‘w.dim[0].ubound’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
mem.f90:13:0: Warning: ‘w.dim[1].lbound’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
mem.f90:13:0: Warning: ‘w.dim[1].ubound’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
mem.f90:13:0: Warning: ‘w.dim[0].ubound’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
mem.f90:13:0: Warning: ‘w.dim[0].lbound’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
mem.f90:13:0: Warning: ‘w.dim[1].ubound’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
mem.f90:13:0: Warning: ‘w.dim[1].lbound’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
```

However, running the program with `valgrind`, as well as compiling with `-fbounds-check`, `-fsanitize=address`, or `-fsanitize=leak` does not give any error. Furthermore, the instruction `deallocate(w)` at the end does not crash the program, suggesting that `w` contains the memory allocated by `get_matrix` and, hence, one does not need to allocate `w` in the main program.

At the same time, including `allocate(w(2,2))` in the code suppresses the compiler warning. Despite having the impression that the same memory is allocated twice, `valgrind` does not report a memory leak and, in fact, reports exactly the same memory usage.

What is the correct way to store an `allocatable` array as result of a function?
Is it necessary to allocate `w` before storing in it the result of `get_matrix`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers by ja72 and Vladimir F are correct.  However, for completeness I'll address another point.  In the statement

```
var = function_ref()
```

where the right-hand side is a reference to a function with an allocatable result, there's actually nothing special about this in regards to the allocatable nature.  That expression is *not* an allocatable entity.

So, our assignment is much like any other

```
var = expr
```

with the right-hand side an expression.  That is, there is no special consideration required for assigning from a function with allocatable result.  (The function result must, of course, be allocated, but that's a different point.)

In the case of the question, the usual intrinsic assignment rules apply.  In particular, we don't need to allocate `w` before the assignment.

---

On

> Furthermore, the instruction `deallocate(w)` at the end does not crash the program, suggesting that `w` contains the memory allocated by `get_matrix` and, hence, one does not need to allocate `w` in the main program.

There are again other things to say.  The function result of `get_matrix` is itself deallocated after being used in the assignment.  `w` is a separate entity from the function result and the intrinsic assignment causes the allocation of `w`.

So, no you do not "prolong the scope of the result": you've have *copied* it, to a newly allocated variable, and then deallocated once it is finished with.  Consider instead an expression like

```
var = function_ref() + 1
```

Again, we have an expression to assign, but would we expect the function result to "persist"?

Consider also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57606191/3157076).

Answer (score 5):

No need to pre-allocate, or deallocate. The compiler will take care of this. The following code works as expected with Intel fortran.

```
program Console1
implicit none
! Variables
real(8), allocatable :: A(:,:)
integer :: i, j

! Body of Console1

A = get_matrix(6,4)

do i=1, size(A,1)
    print '(*(g9.4),1x)', A(i,:)
end do    

contains

function get_matrix(n,m) result(res)
integer, intent(in) :: n,m
real(8), allocatable :: res(:,:)
integer :: i

    allocate(res(n,m))
    res = 0d0
    forall(i=1:min(n,m)) res(i,i)=1d0

end function

end program Console1
```

Output:

```
1.000    0.000    0.000    0.000
0.000    1.000    0.000    0.000
0.000    0.000    1.000    0.000
0.000    0.000    0.000    1.000
0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000
0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000
```

PS. Put functions inside the program declaration using a `contains` keyword. That way they are not external functions and no interface declaration is required.

Comment: I'd argue that the original `kind=kind(0.d0)` is better than your `8`. It is at least portable, if a bit long.

Comment: @VladimirF - Yes, but I choose brevity here,

Answer (score 3):

There are many similar bugs in the GCC bugzilla and are considered a problem with your compiler, not with your code. Some are already fixed, some are not [67679](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67679) [66459](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66459) [88455](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88455) and more (many duplicates).

Try the most recent version of the compiler, but it may still persist.

As a workaround I use`-Wno-maybe-uninitialized`.